# How activeMQ is able to execute classes which are not their in its classpath

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, classloader

Here we have a deployment of webserver and activeMQ deployment in production environment.

activeMQ is started with out any classpath setting applied to it.

Messages get posted and get consumed by MessageHandlers on the activeMQ box.

It works fine but i have a question.

**How activemq server is executing the classfile as the MessageHandler classes are not in its classpath?**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new ClassLoader, e.g. an URLClassLoader with new paths and/or files, load classes from it and invoke methods in that class using reflection.

I suppose that's what ActiveMQ is doing.